# Transformation of Quadric Surfaces

Tags: transformation, quadratic-forms

Is there a transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that a hyperboloid of one-sheet can be mapped to a hyperboloid of two-sheets using such transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if you want $T$ to be continuous. There's a theorem that says the continuous image of a connected set is connected. The one sheet hyperboloid has one component, while the two sheet hyperboloid has two components. This means the two sheet hyperboloid is *not* connected, so no continuout $T$ could map the (connected) one sheet hyberloid to the not-connected two sheet hyperboloic.

More basically, suppose $T$ were continuous, and maps the one-sheet to the two sheet. Take two points $p,q$ on different sheets of the two sheet hyperboloid. Let $a,b$ be the points on the one sheeted hyperboloid for which $T(a)=p$ and $T(b)=q$. [Note that $a,b$ are different points on the one sheet hyperboloid, since otherwise from $a=b$ would follow that $p=T(a)=T(b)=q$, but we chose $p,q$ as points on different sheets of the two sheet hyperboloid, so that we know $p$ and $q$ are different.] Now draw a continuous curve $C$ in the one sheeted hyperboloid connecting $a$ to $b$. Then restrict the map $T$ to this curve, and the image $T(C)$ would connect $p$ to $q$. That's clearly not possible since $p,q$ are on different sheets of the two sheeted hyperboloid.

Comment: Alright thanks so much. :)